# type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: android, wordpress

I was trying to get the content from my wordpress website. I wanted the content from the specify post as you can see there: (understanding, this website is not real but it came from real website, I just replace the different title, url, etc.) http://pastebin.com/PWuC8usi

Error said:

> Error parsing data Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject

```
 private void parseJSON(String data){

        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(data);
            //JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("posts");
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("content");
            Log.i("App", "jsonMainNode = "+jsonMainNode);

            int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();
            Log.i("App", "jsonArrLength = "+jsonArrLength);



            for(int i=0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {

                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String postTitle = jsonChildNode.getString("title");
                String postUrl = jsonChildNode.getString("url");
                String postDate = jsonChildNode.getString("date");
                String postContent = jsonChildNode.getString("content");

                tvPostTitle.setText("Page title: " +postTitle);
                tvPostUrl.setText("Page URL: " +postUrl);
                tvPostDate.setText("Date: " +postDate);
                tvPostContent.setText("Content: " +android.text.Html.fromHtml(postContent).toString());
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("App", "Error parsing data " +e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The program received HTML, not JSON.

This is indicated by the *non-[JSON](http://www.json.org/)* text which begins with ["<!DOCTYPE.."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration), per the error message.

Only JSON can be parsed as JSON.

In any case the error is elsewhere, perhaps with the request of the data (eg. wrong resource; missing requested type) or perhaps with the server response (eg. not JSON; 40x? 500?). Look at the *actual* response/data contents *and* the received HTTP status code for clues.

Comment: Sorry for late respond, I was busy and happened forgot about ths.

Comment: how can I make the program to recieve the HTML but then convert to JSON? I am using the Wordpress API. Restful API.